# Suppress "Unifying Receiver RQR24 Device Update"?

Tags: update-manager, logitech-unifying

Ubuntu prompts me that I need to install the Logitech "Unifying Receiver (RQR24) Device Update", because there's a security hole in it.

Thing is: **I don't care**, and I'm *using* one of the devices that'll be bricked.

How do I get it to stop prompting me about the update?

Comment: Can't. Do the update. Don't use any devices during the update. Power OFF. Power ON. Boot Ubuntu. Replug the dongle if required. It'll all work fine.

Comment: It won't work fine though. The mouse I'm using is explicitly on the "no longer supported" list. My threat model doesn't include drive-by actors, and this particular box is not sensitive in any way (I use it for watching TV), so I literally *don't care* about the vulnerability.

Comment: I'm not sure that your analysis is correct. Updating the firmware in the dongle should have nothing to do with a "no longer supported" mouse, or it getting bricked. Do as you wish.